# How to get average time of datediff?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

With the below query I'm getting the DATEDIFF of each 
record in the table.

How can I get it to get the AVG of the datediff of all records?

I don't care about the date only the time.

```
SELECT 
right('0' + convert(float,datediff 
                    (second, callstartdt,endstartdt)/ 60 % 60), 2) + ':' +
right('0' + convert(float,datediff 
                    (second, callstartdt,endstartdt)% 60),2)  as total_time
FROM times
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f01c6/2

I have sql 2012.

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: There's really no point in the `% 60` portion of the minutes calculation if it will never display beyond minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just plop an `AVG()` in there:

```
SELECT 
    right('0' + convert(float,AVG(datediff (second, callstartdt,endstartdt))/ 60 % 60), 2) + ':' 
  + right('0' + convert(float,AVG(datediff (second, callstartdt,endstartdt))% 60),2)  as total_time
FROM times
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f01c6/4/0)

Comment: It doesn't seem OP is concerned that anything will run longer than a few minutes. The minutes portion will be incorrect (or misleading) once it gets over an hour though.

Comment: @shawnt00 That's true, my assumption is that the sample values are representative.

Comment: @shawnt00 why would it be incorrect if it run longer?

Comment: Because `% 60` will ensure it never counts higher than 59.

Comment: @jfishbow It's a limitation of the format you've chosen, to see if it has impact all you have to do is run:
`SELECT AVG(datediff(second, callstartdt,endstartdt))
FROM times`
, if it's 3600 or higher then your format is insufficient, if not, you're set.

Answer (score 0):

```
with avg_s as (
    select avg(datediff(ss, callstartdt, endstartdt)) as ss from times
)
select
    ss / 86400 as days,
    ss % 86400 / 3600 as hours,
    ss % 3600 / 60 as minutes,
    ss % 60 as seconds,
    concat(
        format(ss / 3600, '00:'), /* could be greater than 24 */
        format(ss % 3600 / 60, '00:'),
        format(ss % 60, '00')
    )
from avg_s
```

The older hack with datetime would have you doing something like this but a lot of it is deprecated in later versions of Sql Server.

```
select cast(avg(
        cast(cast(endstartdt as datetime) -
        cast(callstartdt as datetime)
    as float)) as datetime)
from times
```